# Python Pandas concatenate dataframes and rename index

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes, all of which have 50 columns and one row. The same column names are used in each dataframe, and the single row is always indexed as 0. I'm trying to concatenate them to make viewing and comparing the data easier.

```
features = pd.concat([raw_features, fea_features, transformed_features], axis=0)
```

Now I want to rename the rows. I've tried several things including:

```
features = pd.concat([raw_features, fea_features, transformed_features], axis=0).reindex(['Raw_pulltest', 'FEA', 'Transformed_pulltest'])
```

which gives the error `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

and

```
features = pd.concat([raw_features, fea_features, transformed_features], axis=0).reset_index().reindex(['Raw_pulltest', 'FEA', 'Transformed_pulltest'])
```

which gives me the structure I want, except all values are now `nan`.

Please can you help me rename the index on the concatenated dataframe?

Comment: Rename the rows? Why aren't you passing the right rows from the start to pd.concat? Try to share some data samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keys` parameter in `pd.concat`:

Try this:

```
pd.concat([raw_features, fea_features, transformed_features], 
          axis=0, keys=['Raw_pulltest', 'FEA', 'Transformed_pulltest'])\
  .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Example:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1]],index=[0])

d2 = pd.DataFrame([[2,2,2]],index=[0])

d3 = pd.DataFrame([[3,3,3]], index=[0])

pd.concat([d1,d2,d3],axis=0, keys=['d1','d2','d3']).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    0  1  2
d1  1  1  1
d2  2  2  2
d3  3  3  3
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. Now I get the following index `('Raw_pulltest',0), ('FEA',0),('Transformed_pulltest',0)` why are my index values tuples?

Comment: Can you show me what fea.info()  What does that look like? Put results in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot your `reset_index` statement, with that it works great! :) Thanks